# Good ways to store large number of text files of small size typically in kilobytes and perform analytics

Tags: hadoop, redis, analytics, bigdata, nosql

I have large number of text files(raw text) that contain data from various collected sources such as syslog, crash decodes,config data of routers/switches/... as separate files. I have to store such files and perform some analytics on them. These files are small in size(typically in kB at max 10MB) but they are large in number. If I have to go for Hadoop, I think it doesn't make sense as block size in HDFS is 64MB by default. So should I go with MongoDB or other NoSQL stores? Please suggest.
A sample file (This is only one type of file, there are many more of other types) looks like this : 
(One of the things among many that I want to analyse is how many crashes happened which have thread id as 1? ) 
.....................................................................................................................................................

Crashed pid:1956835686 (pkg/bin/nvgen) Time:Mon Dec  9 07:41:18 2013

Thread:1 received signal:11 - SIGSEGV. Segmentation fault. Sender:kernel pid:1
Signal specific information: Signal code 1 - SEGV_MAPERR. Address not mapped. Accessed BadAddr 0x0 at PC 0x0.
Core dump file name:dumper_harddisk:/dumper/nvgen.sparse.node0_RSP0_CPU0.ppc.Z

Registers info

r0       r1       r2       r3
  R0   00000000  e7fff6d0  00b33844  40000000
            r4       r5       r6       r7
  R4   e7fff6d8  00000038  e7fff6d8  00000018
            r8       r9      r10      r11
  R8   00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
           r12      r13      r14      r15
  R12  24000042  00b33844  e7fffa60  00000004
           r16      r17      r18      r19
  R16  e7fffa74  e7fffa88  e7fffb4c  00000000
           r20      r21      r22      r23
  R20  00aac26c  00000000  00000000  00000007
           r24      r25      r26      r27
  R24  0ff880c4  00000000  e7ffffb1  00000000
           r28      r29      r30      r31
  R28  48020778  e7fffb7c  e7fffb4c  00000000
           cnt       lr      msr       pc
  R32  00000000  00000000  4000d932  00000000
           cnd      xer
  R36  44000044  00000000

Comment: as you said you are going to  perform some analytics on data so you don't  only need a nosql storage. for hadoop's case you need hbase for storage and hive for analytics.

Comment: But file size is very less in my case typically in kilo bytes. Does it make any sense to use hbase and hadoop?

Comment: That's true but could you put all your files in one? (group all your log files just in one big file?)

Comment: Actually they are so large in number that it is time consuming to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write your text files into one [sequence file](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html). There files are based on a key / value structure and can be extended. In a serious IT architecture I'd recommend a queuing mechanism (e.g. JMS) for such cases.

Comment: What is your take on using MongoDB instead of Hadoop?